# How can I customize the HTML in a Django UserCreation form?

Tags: django, django-forms

In my views I have something like:

```
form = UserCreationForm()
return render(request, "mypage.html", {'form': form})
```

In my view I have the somewhat magic:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Which produces the HTML for a form.  How can I customize this HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly, it's actually quite simple. The format, taken from the django docs, is as follows:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <label for="id_subject">Email subject:</label>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="id_message">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.sender.errors }}
    <label for="id_sender">Your email address:</label>
    {{ form.sender }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
    <label for="id_cc_myself">CC yourself?</label>
    {{ form.cc_myself }}
</div>
```

the complete instructions can be found here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/
just scroll down to the "Customizing the Form Template" section

Answer (score 0):

`form.as_p` renders the form using internal Django logic (basically a big string of fields wrapped in paragraph tags)

You can't customize that (unless you override the `as_p` method on your Form subclass).

What you can do is just create your own HTML and manually render the form fields within it.

So, in your `mypage.html` you could do:

```
<form>
{{ form.username }}
{{ form.password }}
</form>
```

There are numerous methods available on each field, just read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/